# Sell numbered seats in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im looking for a way to sell numbered Tickets on Prestashop. For example I have a ticket for a Hockey Game. Seats are numbered, so when I sell a ticket for seat A8, this seat is gone and can not be sold again. The seats are all the same price for a given Game or Season. A customer should be able to choose his seat from a dropdown list.

Comment: You need to tell us more informations. Do your customers can chose their seats? Is their different prices depending on seat location?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add product quantities and enable out of stock feature.
Then set the product quantity to 1. 
And not allowing orders when the product quantity is less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Attribute "Seats" with value of all seat numbers and allow add one quantity for each of Seats values